# Files with unknown file names

Tags: r, statistics

I am having a folder where I have a lot of csv files in it.

Can I read all of them, for example as `zoo` object without knowing the file name?

**UPDATE**

I tried that:

```
files <- list.files( "C://Users//ramid//Desktop//Files//" );
(na.omit(files))
for( i in files ) {
    filePath <- gsub(" ","", paste("C://Users//ramid//Desktop//Files//",files[i],".csv"), fixed=TRUE)
    cat(filePath)
    df <- read.csv(gsub(" ","", filePath, fixed=TRUE), header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

However I am getting an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C://Users//ramid//Desktop//Files//NA.csv': No such file or directory
```

I do not have any `NA` in my files list.

Comment: `x <- list.files( "path/to/myfolder" ); for( i in x ){ read.csv(); blah; blah; blah}`

Comment: @SimonO101 when I want to print the list of files function I get `character(0)` in the output. How to output them?

Comment: You probably didn't put it the folder path correctly. It can't find the folder. Make sure you are using forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: @SimonO101 I tried it with your method. However I am still getting an error message. It would be great if you could see my update

Comment: @SimonO101 I am on a windows system and it either does not work with `/` I am getting the same output as in the update.

Comment: `"C:/Users/ramid/Desktop/Files"`

Comment: Why double forward slashes? `/` between each directory not `//`. You need to escape `\` because `\` is a special character so to tell `R` that you have a literal `"\"` you use `"\\"`, but this is not the case with `/`.

Comment: I'd recommend setting `full.names` to `TRUE`, this way you get the full path from `list.files`, and your construction of the full path name is no longer needed (saves code).

Comment: And why are you replacing `" "` by `""`? Just removing spaces does not lead to a valid path as far as I know.

Comment: ...and note that the `(na.omit(files))` does not do anything when you do not assign the result to a variable. This would work: `files = na.omit(files)` (note that the `()` around `na.omit()` is not needed). The `;` at the end of `list.files` is not needed.

Comment: Note that `read.zoo` can read in multiple files at once.  Just give it a vector of filenames and it will read in each one and then merge them (in the sense of `merge.zoo`) at the end giving a wide zoo object.  See `?read.zoo` and also the example in the Other Comments section of `vignette("zoo-read")` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `list.files` and `lapply`:

```
list_of_files = list.files('.', pattern = '*csv', full.names = TRUE)
list_of_csv_contents = lapply(list_of_files, read.csv)
list_of_zoo = lapply(list_of_csv_contents, zoo)
```

Or wrap both the `read.csv` and `zoo` in one step:

```
read_into_zoo = function(path) {
    contents = read.csv(path)
    zoo_contents = zoo(contents)
    return(zoo_contents)
   }
list_of_zoo = lapply(list_of_files, read_into_zoo)
```

This strategy of storing things in lists/arrays/vectors/matrices and using `apply` style looping is a strategy that works very well in R.

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! However I am still getting an error, `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'AT0000613005.csv': No such file or directory`. However this file really exists!

Comment: The simplest option is to set `full.names` to `TRUE`. You will then get the complete path form `list.files`.